# SharePoint LINQ problem!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development, sharepoint-server

I am following all steps from this [Microsoft blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff742312(v=office.14).aspx) but I am facing some errors

- `<EmployeesItem>` this is an unknows command.
- `where emp.Project.DueDate`is not working

I have the following code:

[image]

Comment: Have you added reference to Linq?

Comment: Yes I have added

Comment: What is the error when compiling code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is due to dll version, check the version compatability,if the version mismatch it will not compile

Comment: One thing I noticed was his SPLinq.cs was 58kb mine was only 28kb is this the problem?

Comment: Check the dll version of linq, are you using .net framework 4 or 4.5, this has the problem

Comment: .net framework 4

Comment: You need to get the compatible version of the linq dll, your current version will not be useful